# How do I remove a member from a board? Follow up question

Tags: trello, account-management

Saw an earlier post with this question but the answer didn't help. As an organization admin I expect to see the "Remove from Board" option when I click on the member's avatar.... but, the only things in the drop-down are:

- *Change Permissions...(Normal)* (which is not clickable)
- *View Member's Board Activity*

Help?

Comment: Please add a link to the other question.

Answer (score 5):

Organization admins can't remove members from a board.  You must be a board admin to do this.  You can tell who the board admins are by looking at their avatars on the boards page; admins will have a blue square in the lower right-hand corner.